# Printing file input. System.out.println();

Tags: echo, stdout, stdin

So i have a file called input that contains the following: A B C D Foo . I already created a program that prints each of the elements on a separate line, but for  the life of me, i can't seem to print the elements in the file like they are. I tried numerous approaches, but haven't gotten it.

Here's my program:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class EchoLetters {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IO Exception {
       String word;
       Scanner dataFile = new Scanner(new File("input"));

       System.out.println() //where I'm stuck. Should printout "A B C D Foo"

       while ( dataFile.hasNext() ) {
               word = dataFile.next();
               System.out.println(word);
              }
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println()` expects a parameter to be printed. If you don't pass it any parameters, it will only call `newLine()`.

Here's one way of printing the file content:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    Scanner dataFile = new Scanner(new File("file"));
    while (dataFile.hasNextLine()) {
        s.append(dataFile.nextLine()).append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    System.out.println(s.toString()); //where I'm stuck. Should printout "A B C D Foo"
}
```

Comment: I should of been more explicit in my question, but I also wanted the each element to be printed on a separate line like i had. I would i go about doing that now?

Comment: btw, Vlad, this is exactly the kind of situation where you should be using a StringBuilder instead of concatenating strings. Each `wholeText += ...` creates a new string by copying over the previous wholeText, plus the righthand side string. For instance, if your lines were "a", "bb", "ccc", "dddd" then the first iteration would copy over "a", the second would copy "abb", the third would copy "abbccc", and the last would copy "abbcccdddd". That's 20 copies for 10 original characters! More generally, it's an O(n^2) approach, which scales very badly.

Comment: @JTurner I would create a `List<String> words` which I would populate in the while loop with `dataFile.nextLine().split(" ");` and after printing the file, I would also print the list of words. Be careful to extract `dataFile.nextLine()` to a variable and not call it twice in a row. Sorry for the delay.